# How can I collapse my child tr right underneath its parent column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I want to collapse "tr" in "child tr" as in my code, but I can't collapse it right underneath its parent tr. It works properly when I try it on a JSFiddle, but it doesn't when working on it on my editor and live previewing it. In this case, both "child tr" shows at the end of the table.

I tried all the answers I've found on StackOverflow and several fiddles, but I can't fix the problem, so I believe I am missing something and I can't understand what, unfortunately.

Here is my code:

```
<table>

    <tbody id="mainTableBody" class="topborder" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">      
        <tr class="rowheader1">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Curating</td>
            <td>The Book Affair</td>
            <td>Automatic Books</td>
            <td>2009</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="projectinfo1">
            <td></td>
            <td class="align-top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit id odio minima eos fugiat a aut veniam quasi in, enim quis, iure adipisci ratione, et atque velit distinctio consequuntur nisi!</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit id odio minima eos fugiat a aut veniam quasi in, enim quis, iure adipisci ratione, et atque velit distinctio consequuntur nisi!
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit id odio minima eos fugiat a aut veniam quasi in, enim quis, iure adipisci ratione, et atque velit distinctio consequuntur nisi!
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit id odio minima eos fugiat a aut veniam quasi in, enim quis, iure adipisci ratione, et atque velit distinctio consequuntur nisi!</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="rowheader2">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Project Management</td>
            <td>Fragile?</td>
            <td>Pentagram Stiftung</td>
            <td>2013</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="projectinfo2">
            <td></td>
            <td>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</td>
            <td>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
                Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
                Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>

</table>
```

My CSS:

```
body {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}

.rowheader {
    display: table-row;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}

.projectinfo1 {
    display: none;
}

.projectinfo2 {
    display: none;
}
```

And this is my very easy script function:

```
$(".rowheader1").click( function() { $(".projectinfo1").toggle(); } );
$(".rowheader2").click( function() { $(".projectinfo2").toggle(); } );
```

And lastly, the fiddle I made out of it, which works as I would: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tibo/Lgjpr47t/3/)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just curious, have you included jQuery in your code?

Comment: did you used jquery plugin <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

Comment: _“In this case, both "child tr" shows at the end of the table.”_ - I don’t see how merely switching the value of the `display` property should be able to change the order of elements … What happens when you leave out the last two CSS rules shown, so that everything is visible from the start - elements in “wrong order” then as well? If so, that would indicate that either your HTML is faulty, or additional formatting gets applied.

Comment: @Mirakurun yes I actually included the very last jQuery version

Comment: @04FS if I take out the "display: none" rule indeed elements are still in the wrong order. What I really can't grasp is why in the JSFiddle is working properly. Might it be because of some other parts of my code?

Comment: _“Might it be because of some other parts of my code?”_ - well yeah, most likely … but there is little we can do to help you, if we only know the working version.

Comment: @04FS I know, but thanks very much nevertheless. But do you actually believe this is the best way to design and code a table that has to have both sortable columns and collapsible rows?

Comment: This is the first time you mention this is somehow sortable … could it be _that_ is what messes up the order in the first place? Depending on how that functionality is initialized, it might move the rows around in a different way than you intended.

Comment: @04FS you're right, I am sorry for the omission. I am using a plugin called tablesorter, and I believe it might be its fault, because as soon as I insert it in the fiddle, that also stops working. So I guess I have to find a different plugin probably...

Comment: What do you need to sort _by_ - only contents of the row headers, or also by the project info? It might make more sense to not use two separate rows, but put the additional content _into_ the cells of the header rows. initially hidden, and then toggle all those elements inside the row.

Comment: Thank you very much @04FS that's a good idea! I actually started over to polish the code and now seems to be working well!

Answer (score -1):

What's your jquery version? Try a version higher than 1.9 may help.

Comment: I actually included the very last version of jQuery